# Post-build script with electron-builder

Tags: electron, electron-builder

Is it possible to run some sort of script post-build before packing the installer with electron-builder? I need to generate an extra file that should be distributed but I need the binary, the .exe, to generate it.

Comment: what about launching it from npm and use  "node_modules/.bin/build && ...then" ?

Comment: @Dan that means my generated file is not included in the installer.

Comment: ahhh, I see,  'post-build before packing' ...