# Is it possible to run a post build script for electron-builder?

Tags: electron, electron-builder

This script will generate other files(exes, config files) that my electron program will depend on. Is there a way to set this up in electron-builder?

My problem is same as [this unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44492003/post-build-script-with-electron-builder).

My target output is nsis, right now.

Comment: If you just want to include additional files in your installer then you don't need a post build script for doing so. Maybe you want to do more?

Comment: @Asesh, yes, I want to build some other executables that the electron program will rely on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use electron-builder [`hooks`](https://www.electron.build/configuration/configuration#hooks) to run scripts on various packaging and building events.